# "Too many redirects" ONLY when trying to access wp-admin page

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, htaccess

I figured I would ask my own question seeing as the duplicate question(s) still haven't been answered.

For some reason after my fresh install of Wordpress 4.9.1 on my Ubuntu VPS, enabling my "flexible" SSL issued by Cloudflare, and finally switching my URLs in Wordpress (from "https://foo.com" to "https://foo.com") I can no longer access my admin panel.

**Attempted Fix #1:** Clearing browser(s) cookies, cache, and saved data, *as well as* any Cloudflare caches.

**Attempted Fix #2:**
Modifying `wp-config.php` with the code:

```
define('WP_HOME' , 'https://foo.com');
define('WP_SITEURL' , 'https://foo.com');
```

**Attempted Fix #3:** Disabling `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html/`

None of the above has worked and unfortunately I still cannot access the admin panel. However, the default wordpress homepage loads just fine at the correct secure, "https" URL.

Answer (score 57):

I found a solution that fixed my issue.

Sources:

A.) https://sharpten.com/blog/2018/01/17/wordpress-stuck-many-redirects-error-loop-using-ssl.html

B.) (Sublink within A) https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/

Excerpt: 
Adding the following lines of code at the end of my `wp-config.php` file resolved the redirect conflict.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: [There's a plugin for that](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl/)

Comment: In case someone else stumbles onto this - those two lines worked for me, but only if I placed them at the top of `wp-config.php`.

Comment: This answer did not work for me.

Comment: If above did't help, you may try to add following line *above*:

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); and/or: "SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS on the top" (without quotes, on the top of the file before anything else) to your .htaccess

Comment: If you use cloudflare, set SSL/TLS encryption mode to Full. That's it! It will load like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Should then the line be deleted or keep it?

Comment: This Answer did not work for me neither solution from @S1awek

Comment: The problem happened to me when disabling cloudflare plugin as I had an error with it and needed to reset it and log again. adding this code to the top of wp-config file fixed it and I could enter and re-enable cloudflare plugin, and then removing it from wp-config with no issue.

Comment: Thanks @JakirHossain ! Changing the SSL/TLS setting in Cloudflare from `Flexible` to `Full` worked for me. It seems like a better choice than manually modifying `wp-config.php`, unless as a last resort.

Comment: Worked for me, thank you!! For the context, I am redirecting requests from a public facing nginx with SSL enabled to apache2 in home LAN. Apache2 hosts actual wordpress instances without SSL enabled.

Answer (score 18):

I used the above answer by Matt and added one else case as well:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
else
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='off';
```

It worked. I had also placed it at the beginning of the wp-config.php

Comment: worked. Also it needs to be added to TOP after `<?php` otherwise it would give permission access [error while accessing wp-admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/317407/189275)

Comment: This worked for me while the solution without the else didn't.

Comment: Thanks you made my day :) thanksssssssssssssssss

Comment: Thanks man, worked foe me !!!

Answer (score 5):

Put this code in `wp-config.php` in the first line inside the PHP tag.

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=="/index.php")
{
define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
}
else
{
define('WP_HOME','http://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourdomain.com');
}
```

But don't forget to replace your site URL in the place of `yourdomain.com`

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, our wp-admin folder permissions was set to 777, which means everyone can read, write or execute to this folder.

We logged onto the server, and found an error saying "wp-admin cannot be writable by group."

We changed our permissions so the folder was not writable by group or world (755), and the admin area was immediately accessible.

(This permissions change did happen seemingly randomly for us. Our website's team didn't even have access to the server at the time wp-admin just stopped working and we still don't know how this setting was changed. The site had been up for several years beforehand.)

Comment: I've had the same problem and found several folders with 775 perms: wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes. Changing them to 755 and now in the process of running malware scans to ensure nothing nefarious is afoot. Thank you!

Comment: This was our issue too, and was the result of a hack. Changing permissions to 755 worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the 'Too many redirects' on wp-admin only after migrating to a new server.

The problem was incorrect permissions on the folder wp-admin plus the top-level files within it. Resetting the permissions fixed the issue.

Hope that is of help to anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Apache's `DirectoryIndex` issue. The `wp-admin` was being accessed by `wp-admin/index.php` but not with `wp-admin` and showing `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

It sounds like Apache's `DirectoryIndex` may be set "incorrectly". Try resetting this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

See the full answer here. 
[Can't access admin dashboard with wp-admin without /index.php after it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/305237)