# Can't access admin dashboard with wp-admin without /index.php after it

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, login, htaccess

After I log in, I'm redirected to `example.com/wp-admin/`, which has a "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" message. If I type in `example.com/wp-admin/index.php`, everything works just fine. My `wp-config.php` looks fine. This is not a multisite setup.

My `.htaccess` has the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Disabling all plugins, changing theme, and hard code siteurl and home values in `config.php` did not solve the issue.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like Apache's `DirectoryIndex` may be set "incorrectly". Try resetting this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```